# Why do I get SP2-0253

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am getting in my test. But I think linesize is already large enough. I know increase linesize will solve the issue. Please let me know why I am getting SP2-0253 here.

```
SQL> COLUMN sal  HEADING 'Salary' FORMAT $99,999.99
SQL> set lines 10
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> desc sal from emp
Usage: DESCRIBE [schema.]object[@db_link]
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;
SP2-0253: data item 1 ("SAL") will not fit on line
SQL> set lines 20
SQL> /

 Salary
-----------
$800.00

SQL>
```

Comment: COLUMN commands only apply to the column names in the SELECT list when matched exactly. If they differ, then you must use the exact alias in the column list in the select statement.

Answer (score 4):

1) `show linesize` to get the current linesize.  My guess is "80".

2) `set linesize 32767`

3) Run your SQL command.  Check the actual line size.

Comment: see the line: `set lines 10` in my example. So the linesize is 10

Comment: Set linesize to a larger number (32767, for example!), run your SQL, and check the actual line size!  You'll find you've got *more than 10*!  SUGGESTION: try doing a "select" with a positive ... and a negative number ;)

Answer (score 1):

> SP2-0253: data item 1 ("SAL") will not fit on line

The reason is simple. You want the **output format** as:

```
FORMAT $99,999.99
```

Which needs a **linesize** of `11` to be displayed with proper **position** and **alignment** in **SQL*Plus output**.

Let's see:

```
SQL> set linesize 11
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;

     Salary
-----------
    $800.00
```

The simplest way to see how many lines it takes in the output is to check the **LENGTH** of the **underline**:

```
SQL> select length('-----------') length from dual;

    LENGTH
----------
        11

SQL>
```

So, it answers the question "**why the output of 11 lines can't fit in 10 lines**".

**Update** The actual reason for the behaviour is that the **column name is formatted as new column name** and there is no **correct alias** provided in the **select list**.

> COLUMN commands only apply to the column names in the SELECT list when matched exactly. If they differ, then you must use the exact alias in the column list in the select statement.

**Solution** Add same alias name as the column name provided int he format.

```
SQL> COLUMN sal  HEADING 'Salary' FORMAT $99,999.99
SQL> set lines 10
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;
SP2-0253: data item 1 ("SAL") will not fit on line
SQL> select sal Salary from emp where rownum = 1;

    SALARY
----------
       800

SQL>
```

Alternatively,

```
SQL> set linesize 10
SQL> select sal Salary from emp where rownum = 1;

    SALARY
----------
       800

SQL> select sal as "Salary" from emp where rownum = 1;

    Salary
----------
       800

SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;
SP2-0253: data item 1 ("SAL") will not fit on line
SQL> set linesize 11
SQL> select sal from emp where rownum = 1;

     Salary
-----------
    $800.00

SQL>
```

Comment: Why `FORMAT $99,999.99` need a 11 linesize? I was thinking 9 is enough.

Comment: Did you read the complete answer? Did you understand the alignment and position? Did you see in the output the total length of lines is 11?

Comment: Sure I read the answer completely, but I don't know about alignment and position. Why it is 11 for the format, not 9 or 10 or other values.

Comment: See the update, I found the issue is actually with your alias and the column name given in the format command. Due to which, there is a mismatch in the column name in the output.

Answer (score 0):

problem is not in format but in trailing sign for negative numbers. There is no number format to avoid this. Use `to_char` for select your data in required format in conjunction with `substr` to trim result to 10 characters